# How to type a JSON import in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, import

Basically I want to type an imported JSON so I could inspect it easily.
This is what Ive tried:

```
// typings.d.ts

type NetWorkReport = {
  log: {
    version: string
    creator: any
    pages: any[]
    entries: Request[]
  }
}

declare module "*.json" {
  const value: NetWorkReport;
  export default value;
}
```

And my code where I import the file:

```
// index.ts

import * as networkCapture from './networkCapture.json';

console.log(networkCapture.log) // ERROR: Property 'log' does not exist on type '{}'
```

My JSON is huge (Its actually an export from `Chrome DevTools > Network > Export HAR...`). The first lines are:

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "WebInspector",
      "version": "537.36"
    },
    "pages": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2020-03-11T12:21:37.400Z",
        "id": "page_1",
        "title": "https://somewebpage.com",
        "pageTimings": {
          "onContentLoad": 1946.7949999962002,
          "onLoad": 3050.905000010971
        }
      }
    ],

...
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: May you share the JSON as well?

Comment: what does your json file look like?

Comment: I think its only read at execution time but question updated anyway. Btw if there is any way to inference the type from that actual JSON, it would be even better

Answer (score 0):

I have also import the json file on .ts page.

import like.

```
import * as countries from '../../../environments/countries.json';
```

and than get the data in constructor like this.

```
let countriesList: any = [];
countriesList = countries;
```

So you can do like this to get your Json data.